# Why does spark-shell fail with "error: value driver is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession"?

Tags: apache-spark

Below is the code I am trying to execute. I think I am misssing any package but not sure which one I need to import

```
scala> spark.driver.extraClassPath /user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar
    <console>:33: error: value driver is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
           spark.driver.extraClassPath /user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar
                 ^
    <console>:33: error: not found: value user
           spark.driver.extraClassPath /user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar
                                        ^
    <console>:33: error: not found: value hadoop
           spark.driver.extraClassPath /user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar
                                             ^
    <console>:33: error: not found: value ojdbc6
           spark.driver.extraClassPath /user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar


^
```

Comment: `spark-shell --driver-class-path /user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
sc.getConf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath","/user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar")
```

not sure if thats what you need, never used this.

Comment: I am trying to connect to my oracle database from Spark, it throws an error that java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver  ... So trying to add this jar .. but this option also not working

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you entered the following line while being inside `spark-shell` (the prompt `scala>` says so) not before executing it.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar
```

That line looks like it could be part of `conf/spark-defaults.conf` where configuration key and values are separated by whitespace.

You should use `conf/spark-defaults.conf` or start `spark-shell` with `--conf` command-line option as follows:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar
```

Given `spark.driver.extraClassPath` corresponds to `--driver-class-path` you could run `spark-shell` as follows to have the same effect.

```
spark-shell --driver-class-path /user/hadoop/ojdbc6.jar
```

---

You should really use `spark-shell`'s `--jars` command-line option.

> **--jars JARS** Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths.